# Android activities can execute when not in foreground

Tags: android

Android activities can execute when not in foreground. In one page am having chronometer means can i run that with out pause..No means wt i do to run with out pause.. give me any idea.. thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Activities can't be executed when not in foreground.**

But, if you have a Service working for the activity, it will, and then when your activity come back to foreground it will get the updates the service did.

once you start a service, it can be stoped only by the system (in case of low device resources) or if the user want to stop it.

So, I think, that for your problem you should implement a Service, to work in background for your activity.

Read this, just in case. http://bit.ly/gP0EI8

Answer (score 0):

No you cant, onPause() is in the lifecycle of the activity... you cant skip it,